# Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation joining a domain

Tags: windows-server-2012, domain-controller

Today I've had a problem with my Microsoft servers.

This is my environment:

**Windows 2008 R2 standard:**

- Domain Controller (AD)
- Telefon Server

**Windows 2012 R2 Foundation:**

- Web Server (Apache)
- Some other Applications

We have 10 more computers in the network. Today the Windows 2012 Server shutdown with some errors relating to licencing.

What is the easiest way to fix this problem? Win 2008 must be our AD otherwise we have a lot of problems with out telephone software.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be resolved in a license friendly way, and if so you really need to contact the person who sold you the 2012 foundation server and explain your problem there. –possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: ok, i need one short fix and have later time to reinstall the win 2012 server.

Is it possible to buy win 2012r2 standard and reinstall the software?

Comment: [Upgrade of Windows Server 2012 Foundation is not supported.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679892.aspx) I'd like to reiterate, we probably can't help you, contact your vendor. Edit: I just realised you said buy a win 2012r2 and reinstall... Yes you could reinstall everything on a new OS, that's always an option. However you can't use your existing win 2012 R2 Foundation server license.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use Windows 2012 R2 Foundation the way you are trying to.

[`In the Windows Server 2012 Foundation operating system, the server must be a member of a workgroup or, if joined to a domain, joined at the root of the forest as a domain controller.`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679892.aspx)

`In the Windows Server 2012 Foundation operating system, you will also receive a warning message if your server in an Active Directory domain has established a trust with a domain in another forest. If this occurs, remove the trust with the domain in the other forest.`

For my money, the easiest way to fix this problem is to buy a proper Server 2012 R2 Standard license, and use that instead, but you may prefer a different course of action.  I'm having trouble imagining why you couldn't make the Server 2012 R2 Foundation server a domain controller, at least temporarily, to resolve the licensing issue, and promoting a machine to a domain controller is pretty easy, so that's another option.

Comment: Promoting the server to DC still leaves out the part about the telephone software requiring the 2008 servers AD. Which means forcing the server to authenticate using a specific DC, possibly other people have a different take on it, but using sites I've found it unreliable at best.